# F# indentation syntax for for printing

Tags: string, f#, indentation

I'm a bit confused concerning the f sharp indentation. 
If i have the string "foo bar", and i'd like to print only "foo" as an example. Using indentation - how would i achieve this?

And if i would like to print both words?

I have tried something like this:

```
let f = 
  "foo bar"
```

And here i was thinking that maybe this should work:?

```
printfn "foo bar" //prints whole "foo bar"
printfn "foo
world"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not what indentation is for. If you want to get only the part of the string before the whitespace, use [its `.Split()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx). That gives you an array, and you can print the first element of the array.

Comment: I'm completely perplexed by this question.  What on earth gave you the impression that this is what indentation is for?

Comment: Indentation in F# is related to the  structure and the syntax of F# language like python, read: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print off only the first word (`"foo"`), you need to "split" the string and print off the first portion.

You can do this via [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
let f = "foo bar"
let split = f.Split([| ' ' |]) // Split by spaces
let foo = split.[0] // First element in array is "foo"
printfn foo
```

Comment: `f.[0]` is the first character of the string "foo bar", I believe you meant `split.[0]`

Comment: @zaid thanks.. happens when typing in directly. Fixed